# strftime function on R with Minutes:seconds:milliseconds

Tags: r, format, strftime

I have been trying to format some of my data using the strftime function. 
I have a time in Minutes:Seconds:milliseconds

`birds$Total.time
[1]00:03:14
[2]00:03:00
...
[82]00:04:05
strftime (birds$Total.time, format= "%M:%S:%OS")`

but it always gives me an error ("the chain of characters is not in an unanbiguous standard format", translation from french R). Have I missed a step?

Thank your very much in advance for your help!

Comment: There are a couple of things that won't work. First, you cannot have both, `%S` and `%OS` in the format. They are mutually exclusive. The last colon in your time data will need to be replaced with a period. Then it will probably be necessary to create a fictitious date (including the hour) in order to extract the time, something like `paste0("01/01/2016 00:",birds$Total.time)`. Finally, you might need to set `options(digits.secs=2)` to have the "centiseconds" displayed in your data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it still doesn't work. I have tried the following: 'strptime((paste0("01/01/2016 00:",birds$Total.time)),format='%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S')' but it just gives me back lines and lines of NAs.

Comment: This was not an answer but a comment. I didn't want to perform all the required programming steps to achieve the required results. My intention was to indicate a possible way to transform the data into a valid time format. Try 
`options(digits.secs=2); birds.Total.time <- "00:03.14"; strptime(paste0("01/01/2016 00:",birds.Total.time),"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%OS")`.